# mapping function

Tags: hash, notation

I have read a scientific paper which covers some security schemes in mobile ad hoc networks.

I don't understand this notation:
$$H_0\;\;\;\text{ Mapping }\{0,1\}^*\to \mathbb Z_p^*$$
where $p$ is a prime number.

[Link](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijdsn/2013/374713/)  to the paper: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijdsn/2013/374713/

The notation resides in the [table of notations](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijdsn/2013/374713/tab1/). Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

"Mapping" is just a synonym of "function" (or its generalisations in category theory). Here $H_0$ is a function from the set $\{0,1\}^*$ of finite binary strings to the set $\mathbf{Z}_p^*$ of non-zero integers modulo $p$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 1):

The notation
$$H_0\;\;\;\text{ Mapping }\{0,1\}^*\to \mathbb Z_p^*$$
means:

- $H_0$ designates a function
- from the set $\{0,1\}^*$ of all bitstrings (the typical input set for a theroretical hash function; it includes all bitstrings of various finite length, including the empty bitstring); which may becomes clearer noting that

  - $\{0,1\}$ is the set of the possible values for a bit,
  - $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$ is the set of the possible values for two-bit bitstrings,
  - $\{0,1\}^k$ is the set of the possible values for $k$-bit bitstrings,
  - $\{0,1\}^*$ is the union of the above for all $k$ in $\mathbb N$ (here the $^*$ is a shorthand for *any*).
- to the set $\mathbb Z_p^*$, which

  - is the set of equivalence classes for the relation *equivalent modulo* $p$ over the signed integers $\mathbb Z$ (this set of equivalence classes is noted $\mathbb Z_p$), restricted to classes of signed integers that have a modular multiplicative inverse modulo $p$ (here the $^*$ stands for *except for non-invertible elements*; in yet other contexts like $\mathbb Z^*$ it would stand for *except zero*);
  - can thus be assimilated to the set of integers $i$ with $0<i<p$ and $\gcd(i,p)=1$;
  - which, for prime $p$, is simply the set of integers $i$ with $0<i<p$.

Comment: Is this means that H0 is a popular hashing function like (MD5, SHA1,etc...) and takes as input binary string and outputs a signed integer except zero

Comment: @yomna: no, that definition does not say a thing about what $H_0$ is beyond from what set to what set. And it precludes that it is exactly (e.g.) SHA-1, since that has output set $\{0,1\}^{160}$. One option perhaps would be: $SHA-512(x)\bmod p$ (using big-endian convention from 512-bit bitstring to integer), especially if $p\ll2^{512}$

Comment: As I'm beginner in this topic.  What  is your advice for better understanding ? Any suggested links ?

Comment: @yomma: for notations and foundations of cryptography, I like the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/). However it does not cover some advanced subjects used in the article, in particular  bilinear pairings.